# ConfigurationException while launching Apache Cassanda DB: This node was decommissioned and will not rejoin the ring

Tags: cassandra

This is a snippet from the system log while shutting down:

```
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:28:50,995 StorageService.java:3788 - Announcing that I have left the ring for 30000ms
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:29:20,995 ThriftServer.java:142 - Stop listening to thrift clients
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:29:20,997 Server.java:182 - Stop listening for CQL clients
WARN  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:29:20,997 Gossiper.java:1508 - No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:29:20,997 MessagingService.java:786 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-sysengplayl0127.bio-iad.ea.com/10.72.194.229] 2016-07-27 22:29:20,998 MessagingService.java:1133 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [RMI TCP Connection(12)-127.0.0.1] 2016-07-27 22:29:21,022 StorageService.java:1411 - DECOMMISSIONED
INFO  [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:17,534 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/opt/cassandra/product/apache-cassandra-3.7/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

And then while starting up:

```
INFO  [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,316 StorageService.java:630 - Cassandra version: 3.7
INFO  [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,316 StorageService.java:631 - Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,316 StorageService.java:632 - CQL supported versions: 3.4.2 (default: 3.4.2)
INFO  [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,351 IndexSummaryManager.java:85 - Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 397 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
ERROR [main] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,357 CassandraDaemon.java:731 - Fatal configuration error
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: This node was decommissioned and will not rejoin the ring unless cassandra.override_decommission=true has been set, or all existing data is removed and the node is bootstrapped again
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:815) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:725) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:625) ~[apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:370) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:585) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:714) [apache-cassandra-3.7.jar:3.7]
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,358 Gossiper.java:1508 - No local state or state is in silent shutdown, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2016-07-27 22:32:20,359 MessagingService.java:786 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
```

Is there something wrong with the configuration?

Comment: Broke wall of text into correct lines. Fixed punctuation. Created more meaningful title.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue.
Posting the answer so that it might help others.

As the log suggests, the property "cassandra.override_decommission" should be overridden.

start cassandra with the syntax:

cassandra -Dcassandra.override_decommission=true

This should add the node back to the cluster.